# Drawing squares in diagonal line instead of in grid pattern in pygame

Tags: python, pygame, conways-game-of-life

```
import random
import pygame
# Initializing the main varibales:
width = 600
height = 600
cell_size = 10
cols = int(width / cell_size)
rows = int(height / cell_size)
BLACK = (0, 0, 0)
WHITE = (255, 255, 255)

pygame.init()
screen = pygame.display.set_mode((width, height))
pygame.display.set_caption("Conway's Game of Life - Clavio Steltman")


def dead_state(w, h):
    # returns 2d array


def random_state(w, h):
    # returns a 2d array with values between 0 and 1


def draw_cell(x, y, state):
    x_pos = x * cell_size
    y_pos = x * cell_size

    if state[x][y] == 1:
        color = BLACK
    elif state[x][y] == 0:
        color = WHITE

    rect = (x_pos, y_pos, cell_size, cell_size)
    pygame.draw.rect(screen, color, rect, 1)
    pygame.display.update()


def main():
    initial_board = random_state(cols, rows)
    print(initial_board)
    screen.fill((255, 255, 255))
    while True:
        for x in range(cols):
            for y in range(rows):
                draw_cell(x, y, initial_board)
    pygame.display.update()


main()
```

The code above prints sqaures in a diagonal line from the top left to the bottom right, instead of in a grid pattern. Can someone please tell me what I am doing wrong? Does it have something to do with my fore loops or something like that? I'm pretty lost at this point.

Answer (score 0):

It's a typo (In fact many problems are)

Just change

```
    x_pos = x * cell_size
    y_pos = x * cell_size
```

to

```
    x_pos = x * cell_size
    y_pos = y * cell_size
```

Comment: Thank you! I was pulling my hairs out :)

Comment: Typo question are off-topic and should not be a answered, but closed. [Questions about a problem that can no longer be reproduced or that was caused by a simple typographical error.](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic)